# How can I pass argument to a Bash script for 'tee'?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a log output file based on the arguments I pass. I tried the below, which didn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello" | tee -a log_$1.log
```

I want a `log_test.log` to be created, instead `log_.log` is created:

```
./script test
```

Comment: It should work the way you wrote it.

Comment: Is that really the whole script?

Comment: yes, that is the whole script.

Comment: What does `echo "$1"` show?

Comment: if I do echo $1, it would show test

Comment: Then there's no reason why it wouldn't expand the same way in the filename.

Comment: right, but that is not what I'm getting.

Comment: Just to be extra careful, try putting `{}` around the name: `log_${1}.log`

Comment: What does `echo log_$1.log` show?

Comment: Sorry, ${1} does work. I had a typo.  Put it as an answer and I'll mark the question as answered.

Comment: I don't like posting an answer when I can't explain what the problem was and how this solves it. You would need to use `${1}` if the character after `$1` were an alphanumeric character rather than `.`, like if you wrote `log_$1_log`

Comment: I suspect that's what you tried to do, but you posted something different.

Comment: @Barmar Actually, you never need braces on `$1` -- if the character after `$` is a digit, it's assumed to be a single-digit numbered parameter, even if that's followed by more alphanumeric characters. (The flip side of that is you always need braces to get arguments past `$9` -- `${10}` gets the 10th argument, but `$10` gets the first argument followed by a literal "0".)

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score -1):

Using `${1}` would resolve the issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello" | tee -a log_${1}.log
```

Comment: This is not the case. Copy-paste the script from this answer into a new file (don't reuse whatever you have), and try it with and without {}s. You'll see that it works the same

Comment: You are at best answering a question that wasn't asked; please don't encourage poor questions by answering them.

Comment: @chepner They're answering their own question.

Comment: And as you've also pointed out, this does not solve a problem present in the question *as asked*. `log_$1.log` and `log_${1}.log` are equivalent, so this isn't going to help anyone else.